# Do we need a sleep() while running a forever process in Linux?

Tags: linux, multithreading, linux-kernel

I have read that a forever process like daemon should run with a sleep() in their while(1) or for(;;) loop. They say, it is required because otherwise this process will always be in  a run queue and the kernel will always run it. This will block the other process. I don't agree that it will block the other process completely. If there is a time slicing, then it will execute other process. But, certainly it will steal a time from others. Making a delay for other process since this process is always in the run state.  By default, the Linux runs as a round-robin. The first task is swapd, then other tasks . This is a circular link list with first task as swapd(process-id is 0) and then other tasks. I believe this is still based as time sliced. A particular time for each process. These tasks are nothing but the process-descriptor. I believe this link list is maintained by the init process. Please do correct me here If I am wrong. Other question is if we need to give a sleep() then what should be its value? How can we determine the sleep value to get the best results?

Comment: "By default, the Linux runs as a round-robin. " No, the default scheduler is not a simple round robin scheduler. But note that you rarely need sleep in a daemon. instead you want to wait for something to do - e.g. watch file descriptors for events (using select/poll)

Comment: Yep, polling and sleeping is a very poor scheme to use (except maybe in situations where you poll less often than once a minute).  Rather the loop should wait on some message or event -- no need to actually sleep, since the wait does the same thing better.

Answer (score 1):

If your program has useful things to do, don't throttle it. A program can move out of the run queue by doing blocking stuff like IO and waiting.

If you are writing a polling loop that can spin an arbitrary number of times you probably want to throttle it a bit with `sleep` because spinning too often has little value.

That said, polling loops are a means of last resort. Normally, programs perform useful work with every instruction, so they don't sleep at all.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on IO and waiting operations?

Comment: When a thread reads from a file it must block until the bytes are available. During that time the kernel deschedules the thread. One the disk has read something, it will inform the kernel using an interrupt that the IO is completed. The kernel will then mark the waiting thread ready again.

Comment: Is it true even when I am writing on a file? While I write and flush it. The kernel will get time to schedule other job.

Comment: @SHREYASJOSHI the kernel releases the physical CPU to other processes whenever the current thread blocks. Blocking happens for all kinds of reasons, including reading and writing. CPU Resources are usually not being wasted. That's the reason polling loops are discouraged. I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Sleep is almost certainly the wrong solution.

Usually what you do it call a blocking function which wakes you up when there's something for you to do.

For example, if you're a network service you'd want to remain inactive until a request arrives.

In other words, the core of your daemon should not look like this:

```
while(1)
{
    if (checkIfSomethingToDo())
        doSomething();
     else
         sleep(1);
}
```

but rather a little like this:

```
while(1)
{
    int ret = poll(fds, nfds, -1);
    if (ret > 0)
        doSomething();
}
```

Have the kernel put you to sleep until there's actual work to do. It's not hard to implement, you'd be a lot more efficient (not stealing CPU time from others, only to waste it doing no actual work) and your response latency will go down too.

Answer (score -1):

A sleep forces the os to pass execution to another thread and therefore is helpfull, or at least fair. Start with sleep one. Should be ok.

Comment: Not my downvote, but I can explain.  99.99% of all sleep(1) loops are an avoidable introductions of CPU-waste and latency.  Like @usr explains above, the thread/s should either be doing useful work or not running at all, (ie. blocked on I/O or inter-thread signaling).